# Extracting json array in Google Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following structure.

```
ID | json
bla | [{"user": "a@a.de", "timestamp": 0, "status": 1}, {"user": "a@a.de", "timestamp": 1, "status": 2}];
```

etc.

Now I want to read them, so that I have the follwing structure in bigquery.

```
ID | USER | TIMESTAMP | STATUS
bla  a@a.de  0          1
bla  a@a.de  1          2
```

When doing this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING, json_path STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
        return jsonPath(JSON.parse(json), json_path);
"""
OPTIONS (
    library="gs://json_path/jsonpath-0.8.0.js"
);
WITH t AS (
SELECT id, history AS json_column FROM TABLE WHERE history IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
id,
  CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json_column , '$[*].email') AS email,
  CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json_column , '$[*].status') AS status,
  CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json_column , '$[*].timestamp') AS timestamp
FROM t
```

I don't get this row by row, but I get 1 row with sub rows...

Comment: `[{user: 'a@a.de', timestamp: 0, status: 1}, {user: 'a@a.de', timestamp: 1, status: 2}]` is simply a invalid JSON structure -> https://jsonlint.com/ -> *"Error: Parse error on line 1:
[{ user: 'a@a.de', tim
---^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'"* .. So don't expected JSON parsing functions to work correctly

Comment: This is valid JSON -> `[{
 "user": "a@a.de",
 "timestamp": 0,
 "status": 1
}, {
 "user": "a@a.de",
 "timestamp": 1,
 "status": 2
}]`

Comment: im sorry, but this was just example json. I'll change it. But you comment doesn't solve my question

Comment: *"but this was just example json. I'll change it. But you comment doesn't solve my question "* In that case that JSON parser which you use is very loose about validation rules, don't think thats a good thing..

Comment: Again.. This was example data for stackoverflow. I did not ran a linter on it, it should have served for explain what I have as an input

Comment: i hope you meant you didn't used that example data in your application. Because if you did i woudn't trust that JSON parser..

Comment: yes.............

Comment: you need to be clearer because of the comment -> *" but this was just example json. I'll change it. But you comment doesn't solve my question "* it sounded like you tryed mine sugestion and in fact used that invalid JSON format in your application ...

Comment: Please see my updated answer, the json works, this is not the problem. The query is the problem. :)

Comment: *"this is not the problem. The query is the problem. :) "* i assuming you are running standard SQL as you use `ARRAY` SQL datatype as Google BigQuery has native JSON support -> [JSON Functions in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) i would suggest trying the native functions in combination with `UNNEST()`..

Comment: I wouldn't post anything here if I wouldn't have tried everything that I can find on the internet, including all docs of bigquery.

Comment: Please make gs://json_path/jsonpath-0.8.0.js publicly readable, so I can run the query as presented

Comment: it is this: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json2array(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return JSON.parse(json).map(x=>JSON.stringify(x));
"""; 
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'bla' id, '[{"user": "a@a.de", "timestamp": 0, "status": 1}, {"user": "a@a.de", "timestamp": 1, "status": 2}]' json
)
SELECT id, 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x, '$.user') AS user,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x, '$.timestamp') AS `timestamp`,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x, '$.status') AS status
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
  UNNEST(json2array(JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$'))) x
```

with result

```
Row id  user    timestamp   status   
1   bla a@a.de  0           1    
2   bla a@a.de  1           2
```